# Process event with last 1 hour, 1week and 1 Month data in Flink streaming

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have to process each event with last 1 hour , 1 week and 1 month data. Like how many times same ip occurred in last 1 month corresponding to that event.

I think window is for fixed time i can't calculate with last 1 hour corresponding to current event.

If you have any clue please guide what should i use Table, ProcessFunction or global window. Or what approach should i take ?

Answer (score 3):

There's a reason why this kind of windowing isn't supported out of the box with Flink, which has to do with the memory requirements of keeping around the necessary state. Counting events per hour in the way that is normally done (i.e., for the hour from 10:00 to 11:00) only requires keeping around a counter that starts at zero and increments with each event. A timer fires at the end of the hour, and the counter can be emitted.

Providing at every moment the count of events in the previous 60 minutes would require that the window operator keep in memory the timestamps of every event, and do a lot of counting every time a result is to be emitted.

If you really intend to do this, I suggest you determine how often you need to provide updated results. For an update once per minute, for example, you could then get away with only storing the minute-by-minute counts, rather than every event.

That helps, but the situation is still pretty bad. You might, for example, be tempted to use a sliding window that provides, every minute, the count of events for the past month. But that's also going to be painful, because you would instantiate 60 * 24 * 30 = 43,200 window objects, all counting in parallel.

The relevant building blocks in the Flink API are [ProcessFunction](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/stream/process_function.html), which is an interesting alternative to doing this with windows, and custom [Triggers](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/windows.html#triggers) and [Evictors](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/windows.html#triggers) if you decide to stick with windows. Note that it's also possible to query the state held in Flink, rather than emitting it on a schedule -- see [queryable state](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/stream/queryable_state.html).

Comment: Thanks i will try the same.